# How to change sound level with visual indication in Unity

Tags: unity, pulseaudio

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity desktop, sound system is pulseaudio.

I want to have custom shortcuts to change volume, in addition to media keys "audio lower/audio upper".

I created custom shortcuts that call commands `pactl set-sink-volume 0 -5%` and `pactl set-sink-volume 0 +5%`. But unlike media keys, this shortcuts change volume without visual indication.

What is command to change volume and display it's visual level indication, like it works with media keys?

Comment: Unity  as other Gnome-based desktops have `dbus`  and there is a `dbus` method, which you can call to change audio and the change on `dbus` tells Unity to show the popup. But it's been awhile since I've used Unity. If I get around  to using Unity again or dig out my old scrips, I'll post an answer some time.  Otherwise, Martin's answer is good enough to get the job done.

Comment: Interesting.  I know that PulseAudio clients control the server though DBus.  Gnome/Unity heavily use the DBus so it would not surprise me to learn that there is a way to trigger the media OSD by DBus, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 1):

You should able to map `XF86AudioLowerVolume` and `XF86AudoRaiseVolume` to whatever custom key sequences you wish using the usual keymapping configuation tool, in addition to your already dedicated media keys.  There is no restriction on a unique mapping.

Another possible *command line* solution is to use `xdotool` This tool lets you simulate keyboard input using the X11 XTEST extension.  E.g. after installing the package, you should be able to use the commands:

`xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume`

and

`xdotool key XF86AudioRaiseVolume`

to do what you want.

Comment: That's an ingenious  workaround, but it doesn't work for me :(

From console xdotool works fine, volume is changed and indication appears.

But when I assign this command to hotkey, nothing happens :( I tried using full path /usr/bin/xdotool and even made a wrapper script to see what's going on, but script shows that the command worked fine and returned 0.

I think this is some Unity bug, that disallows global hotkey handling while other global hotkey is processed.